# onbeforeunload - detecting type of action (only want navigation buttons, not window exit)

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

in my application I use onbeforeunload to call a function when a page is in its unloading state. Is there any way in that javascript function to determine which action exactly was hit to cause this? My issue is that my page contains two iframes - each their own pages. I have this check for unload for both of the pages but for one of them, I don't want to give the error if the x is clicked to close the browser or window, only when a navigation button is hit. (this way when the user clicks the x to close, they are only prompted if they want to leave the page once). Listed below is a sample of the javascript i used. Thanks again.

```
    function UnLoadWindow() {
        return 'Please do not use Browser Navigation Buttons. Please make sure all work is Saved prior to leaving this page.'

}


window.onbeforeunload = UnLoadWindow;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, so you've probably found a solution already.

But, you could try using the onhashchange event instead of onbeforeunload.  Then it shouldn't fire on close?

Then again, I'm not sure what is in your iframes, and whether or not they can navigate to other pages from there.

It might be helpful though, as it has newURL and oldURL values, so you could use them in a way to tell if a user is going back to a previous page.

Give it a look:

[onhashchange event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onhashchange)